# Check if path is in Program Files

Tags: c#, io

How can I check in C# if the specific path is to directory in "Program Files" ?

C:\Program Files\someDir...     -> is in Program Files

D:\Apps\someDir... -> isn't in Program Files

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything? Like getting the path as a string and checking if it contains "Program files"?

Comment: A little unclear. Are you saying that given a certain directory you want to verify that it exists under the Program Files relative root?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check a path in ProgramFiles(x86) by using the code below:

```
string path = "yourpath";


        var programfileX86 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);

        if (path.IndexOf(programfileX86, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            //Found path
        }
```

Comment: I never knew about the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumeration.  Very nice suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, but there's a counter example: "C:\Program Files(x86)123\Test" is not in "C:\Program Files(x86)"

Comment: Another problem is that "C:/Program Files (x86)/Test" (pay attention on slashes \ and /) should be in "C:\Program Files (x86)"

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the program files path. You can do that with System.Environment:

```
var programFilesPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
```

If you want the 32 bit program files path you would just change the special folder you are looking for (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86). Then I would do a contains:

```
var isInProgramFiles = myPath.ToLower().Contains(programFilesPath.ToLower());
```

That should get you 90% of the way there at least! Best of luck!

**EDIT / Sanitize Note**

As a side note - there are situations where you can have a valid input and this still wouldn't match. For example - using "/" instead of "\". If you want to make sure you handle these boundary cases correctly, you can create a "DirectoryInfo" object from your input string, validate that it is actually a folder and also standardize the formatting for it. That code looks something like:

```
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(inputPath)) return false;
var checkPath = (new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(inputPath)).FullName;
```

In this example "inputPath" is the same as "myPath" was above. That should do a moderately good job of sanitizing the input. Best of luck!

Comment: Once again, a counter example is "C:\Program Files (x86)123\Test" which is not in "C:\Program Files (x86)"; another problem is that "C:/Program Files (x86)/Test" (pay attention on slashes \ and /) should be in "C:\Program Files (x86)"

Comment: For situations like that - or where the folder that is being checked is a network share and a mapped drive you are correct this isn't going to be perfect. That would be why I said 90% of the way there. Some input sanitation is probably necessary (or the OP could use "DirectoryInfo" object to do that for you). I'll add a quick note about that

Answer (score 1):

There're some *interseting* and *subtle* issues with the problem:

1. You should compare paths *case insenstive*, e.g. `"C:\PRogRAM FILES (x86)\Sample"`  is OK
2. *Separators* could be either / or \ so `"C:/PRogRAM FILES (x86)/Sample"` is OK as well
3. You should *break on separatos only*, e.g. `"C:\Program Files (x86)MyData\Sample"` is not OK

The Code:

```
    public static Boolean PathIncludes(String path, String pathToInclude) {
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pathToInclude))
        return false;
      else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        return false;

      String[] parts = Path.GetFullPath(path).Split(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.VolumeSeparatorChar);
      String[] partsToInclude = Path.GetFullPath(pathToInclude).Split(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.VolumeSeparatorChar);

      if (parts.Length < partsToInclude.Length)
        return false;

      for (int i = 0; i < partsToInclude.Length; ++i)
        if (!String.Equals(parts[i], partsToInclude[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
          return false;

      return true;
    }

    public static Boolean InProgramFiles(String path) {
      return PathIncludes(path, Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86))); 
    }
```

//    Tests:

```
    // Supposing that ProgramFilesX86 is "C:\Program Files (x86)"
    InProgramFiles(@"C:\PRogRAM FILES (x86)\Sample"); // <- true
    InProgramFiles(@"C:/PRogRAM FILES (x86)/Sample"); // <- true
    InProgramFiles(@"D:/PRogRAM FILES (x86)/Sample"); // <- false
    InProgramFiles(@"C:/PRogRAM FILES (x86)A/Sample"); // <- false
```

Comment: This is the most complete answer.

Comment: Also this is a little shorter and cleaner:

private bool IsInProgFiles(string path)
{
                var srcPath = Path.GetFullPath(path);
                var checkPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86) + '\\';

                if (srcPath.IndexOf(checkPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
}

Answer (score 0):

If you have a path variable:

```
string path = "/* whatever path */";
```

You can check if it is in a folder `subfolder` this way:

```
path.IndexOf('\\' + subfolder + '\\') != -1
```

Note that in more complex cases `..` may revert you out of a subdirectory, meaning that you are not in folder `f2` if you have something like this:

```
"\\base_on_drive\\subfolder\\f1\\f2\\..\\a_file.txt"
```

The `..` will bump you back into it's parent folder `f1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (path.Contains(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)) || (path.Contains(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)))
```

{

}

Comment: The path isn't going to be equal to program files. The path is *inside* program files...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your program might be running inside of ProgramFiles, you will probably want to get the [fullpath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of any path you're checking (in case you get a relative path).  In addition, C# has a handy [SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enumeration that you can use to get the ProgramFiles directory.

The following code will take in a path, convert it to a fullpath, and check if the ProgramFiles directory can be found inside of it.  You may want to add some error handling (such as checking for `null` paths).

```
static string programfileX86 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);

public bool IsInsideProgramFiles(string path)
{
    // Get the fullpath in case 'path' is a relative path
    string fullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(path);

    return (fullPath.IndexOf(programfileX86, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
}
```

Note: Depending on the systems your code is running in, you may want to check for both `SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles` and `SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesx86`.

Credit goes to Toan Nguyen's for the code to get the ProgramFiles directory: